# how to find numeric values for distinct words in text file using python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, nltk

I have a text file and i want to find numeric values corresponding to all the distinct words present in that file.By numeric value, I mean that I want to assign a unique integer value( not the times of occurrence value ) to it so that I can use that numeric data in weka for text analysis.

Can anyone suggest which function to be used for this.

Comment: By 'numeric value' for each word, do you mean the count of occurrences, as assumed by the answers so far?  Either way, please edit your question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, I originally wrote this thinking that this was a Javascript question (silly me). Hopefully it can be used by any Python-Javascript ninja...

Assuming you are already have all of the text represented in the variable called `fileText`.

```
var words = fileText.replace(/\./, '').split(' ');
var wordsCount = {};
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
   var word = words[i];
   if (!wordsCount[word]) wordsCount[word] = 0;
   wordsCount[word]++;
}
```

`wordsCount` will then be an object representing the number of times each word is used.

Comment: "using python" not `(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)`

Comment: Ah, good call. I thought I had `Javascript` filter turned on when I saw this question. My bad. I'll leave the answer if it can be of any use.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
from collections import Counter

with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

count = Counter()

for word in text.split(): 
    # remove stuff like ,/.
    word = word.rstrip(',.')
    count[word] += 1
```

assuming that each word is split by a space, etc.

Comment: i think your code is counting number of times each word is occurring..is it so? please explain code once.

Answer (score 0):

First you need tokenize your corpus, then simply count the instances:

```
from collections import Counter
from nltk import word_tokenize


with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as fin:
  dictionary = Counter(word_tokenize(fin.read())

for word, count in dictionary.most_common():
  print word, count
```